# Encoding difference in Eclipse and Windows console

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, encoding, console

I have a Python script which works *perfectly* in Eclipse Console (Run configuration).
When I try to launch this script on a Windows 7 console, I have the encoding error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I changde the code page of my Windows console to use the same one as in Eclipse (Window->Perference->General->Worspace->Text file encoding):

```
chcp 1252
```

At the beginning of the script, I add:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
```

But it changes nothing.

It works on Eclipse console, so I do not want to decode/encode all my strings for Windows console.

Have you any idea or advice to fix that behaviour?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem in the Windows 7 console. Which version of Python?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting both eclipse's and the windows cmd line's encodings to Utf-8 and see if that works, unless you absolutely need the cp1252 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Python will expect your 8 bit strings to contain ASCII only, not Unicode. `u'\xc9` is a Unicode character. Perhaps Eclipse is more friendly than Windows 7 console. You should use the `unicode` command to convert characters to Unicode as you get them:

```
value = unicode(value, "utf-8")
```

See [this article](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-does-unicodeerror-ascii-decoding-encoding-error-ordinal-not-in-range-128-mean.htm) for more.